# Pipeline for writing a book for programmers in a collaboration

Tags: latex, markdown, publishing, python-sphinx

I'm a member of a group of enthusiast writers, who decided to collaborate on a cookbook-style book for one of programming languages.

We're trying to pick a pipeline for the collaboration.

I like how [ProGit](https://github.com/progit/progit) is made.

That is Markdown + some custom pre-processing, processed by Pandoc. But I'm concerned that Markdown is too simple for our case.

I look at [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), but I have no experience using it.

I know that LaTeX would work — but I'm afraid that it will scare off the contributors. Also it may be too powerful, and too easy to build a byzantine pipeline if you don't have the necessary experience (which I do not).

Please do not suggest solutions where a person have to write XML by hand or *must* use some *specific* GUI (optionally available GUIs are good, of course). Commercial and non-crossplatform solutions are not an option as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say whether pandoc's extended version of markdown would be too simple for your case unless you say what features you need.  Note also that, if you're able to do a bit of very simple Haskell scripting, you can use the [pandoc API](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) to add features.

Comment: Adding features to Pandoc looks good. I think, we'll try to go that way, thank you.